# Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' because upgrade php version to 7.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo, command-line-interface, fpm

I make some PHP applications and use PDO.
Everything is fine until I remove --purge PHP 7.2 and install PHP 7.4.

The program is running but says "could not find driver".

Install all modules like usual, and have error like this in Ubuntu :

Command:

```
#php -v
```

Result :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:54:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Command:

```
# php -i |grep PDO
```

Result :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

In my info.php

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

In my terminal

```
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
```

So I edited in /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini.
Is I am wrong? Can someone give me a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real one is shown by info.php:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
```

So, I finished the issue with configuring php.ini in fpm.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by making sure I had the package installed: `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mysql`